# Seamless wiggle in After Effects?

Tags: adobe-after-effects, video

I've been trying to find a way to make a seamless wiggle loop but nothing seems to help.

I can't make the wiggle to return to its start point in the end and
***wiggle(x,y)*** doesn't really help either.

I tried to search for plugins but I didn't find any.

Answer (score 4):

To loop a wiggle, you can create two wiggles with similar properties, one reversed in time by using the fifth wiggle function parameter, and blend their output value trough a linear interpolation.

The procedure is fully explained here :
http://www.motionscript.com/design-guide/looping-wiggle.html

The resulting piece of code can replace the simple `wiggle()` formula of any expression.

```
freq = 1;
amp = 110;
looptime = 9; // in seconds

t = time % looptime;
a = wiggle(freq, amp, 1, 0.5, t);
b = wiggle(freq, amp, 1, 0.5, t - looptime);
linear(t, 0, looptime, a, b)
```